# Ангелы на кончике иглы

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Честно говоря, не знаю, относится ли этот вопрос к русскому языку в общем и к фразеологии в частности? Вопрос касается достаточно известного выражения **ангелы на кончике иглы** (или **сколько ангелов может поместиться на кончике иглы?**).
Во-первых, откуда пошло это выражение? Во-вторых, в чем тут вообще суть?
Почему ангелы должны там помещаться, и почему надо решать, сколько их там будет? И как они вообще там могут поместиться?
В общем, хотелось бы что-то узнать об этой сентенции.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Данный вопрос пародирует схоластические диспуты католической церкви в период позднего средневековья. Люди уже стали понимать абсурдность некоторых религиозных построений и пытались найти логическим противоречиям какое-то объяснение на основе логики и священных текстов.

Какие только вопросы не обсуждали схоласты!
*Может ли всемогущий создать камень, который не сможет поднять?

Сможет ли ангел переместиться из одной точки в другую, не перемещаясь через середину пути между этими точками?

Сколько ангелов могут одновременно находиться в одной точке?*

Последний вопрос и послужил основой для рассматриваемого выражения (Фома Аквинский дал на него ответ ― один). Непосредственно кончик иглы и пляшущие ангелы появляются уже только в протестантской сатире на католическую церковь.
Выражение прижилось и стало символом бессмысленного спора ни о чем.